# Dropwizard Add Response Filter for All Resources

Tags: java, dropwizard

How can I add a filter to my **Dropwizard** application that will validate the response that every resource is returning?

Should I use `javax.servlet.Filter` or `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter`

Any examples pertaining to its uses would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a response filter for all the resources using [dropwizard](/questions/tagged/dropwizard) you can do the following :

1. Create a CustomFilter that extends `javax.servlet.Filter` -

   ```
   public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

       public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
           // your filtering task
           chain.doFilter(req, res);
       }

       public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
       }

       public void destroy() {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then register the same to your `Service` that extends `Application` -

   ```
   public class CustomService extends Application<CustomConfig> { //CustomConfig extend 'io.dropwizard.Configuration'

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       new CustomService().run(args);
     }

     @Override
     public void initialize(Bootstrap<CustomConfig> someConfigBootstrap) {
       // do some initialization
     }

     @Override
     public void run(CustomConfig config, io.dropwizard.setup.Environment environment) throws Exception {
       ... // resource registration
       environment.servlets().addFilter("Custom-Filter", CustomFilter.class)
           .addMappingForUrlPatterns(java.util.EnumSet.allOf(javax.servlet.DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
     }
   }
   ```
3. You should now be good to be filtering all the resources using the `CustomFilter` defined above.

Comment: this is what i've done, but I'm keep getting entering the filter before it reaches the filter, while I want it to do it after the resource is done

Comment: @Igor filters are meant for both request filtering and response filtering.. the code within the filter class determines what would be filtered and based on what. Also since the question doesn't state what error you've faced. IMHO there should be another thread for the error you've faced with the details of your configuration instead of asking for one as you did here. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to use is `javax.servlet.Filter`.

`A filter is an object that performs filtering tasks on either the request to a resource (a servlet or static content), or on the response from a resource, or both.`

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

Comment: I also thought about it, do you have an example?